# Using Arabica coffee beans for making instant coffee

Tags: beans, instant, chemistry, arabica

I saw in [this article](https://theroasterspack.com/blogs/news/15409365-10-differences-between-robusta-arabica-coffee) that instant coffee is usually entirely consisting of Robusta beans. Would making a instant coffee of Arabica beans make a better quality instant coffee? Would the process making instant coffee with Arabica beans be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process should be quite the same. At least, according to this wholeseller's [website](https://m.alibaba.com/product/50015932253/100-ARABICA-SPRAY-FREEZE-DRIED-INSTANT.html?subject=100--ARABICA--SPRAY--FREEZE--DRIED--INSTANT&type=product&detailId=50015932253&redirect=1).

As far as I understand this company sells 100% Arabica or Robusta OEM instant coffee.

For example, the well-known Nescafe has several brands for different blends. (I cannot reference these as they are based on many years of aggregated information of myself. I cannot even remember when I first hear some of them.)

- Nescafe Classic is pure Robusta, but this claim is hidden recently. Still, if you Google it with keywords as "%100 percent robusta Nescafe" you may see old web pages.
- Nescafe Gold is a blend, ratios are unknown.
- More recent Nescafe Dolce Gusto is 30% Arabica, 70% Robusta. So, I doubt the Arabica ratio of Gold is less than 30%.